# How to add a delay between shots in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to coding and have tried to make a 2D shooting game. The shooting works fine except for the fact that the time between shots is too fast. I have it set so that if space bar is held down, a shot will be fired. The problem with this is that it fires at an extremely fast rate. I would like it to fire 2/3 shots per second. I was wondering what the best way to do this is. Here is my current code for shooting:

`if(spaceDown && shots.length < 20){
     shots.push(new Shot(player.x, player.y));
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of whether firing is possible in a variable that should persist across game loop executions and reset it after a delay.

```
let cooldown = false;
```

```
if(cooldown == false && spaceDown && shots.length < 20){
     shots.push(new Shot(player.x, player.y));
     cooldown = true;
     setTimeout(() => cooldown = false, 300);
}
```